# How can I improve an Octopus Energy API on python and produce a readable chart?

Tags: python, api, matplotlib

I am trying to build an API to Octopus Engergy and I can make an API call and retrieve energy consumption data by an  hourly unit over a few days like so:

```
download_manager = DownloadManager(meter_mpan=meter_mpan,
                                   meter_serial=meter_serial,
                                   api_key=octopus_api_key)

s_elec_consumption = download_manager.create_elec_consumption_s()
print(s_elec_consumption)

r = download_manager.retrieve_electricity_consumption(meter_mpan=meter_mpan, meter_serial=meter_serial,period_from='2021-02-18T00:00:00Z',
                                                                period_to='2021-02-19T00:00:00Z')

print(r.json().keys())
r.json().keys()

dict2 = r.json()['results']

# I slice the data from the APi into lists to make it easier to read in a chart (see below) 
c = 0
consumption = []
utc = []
time_period = []
for i in dict2:
    consumption.append(dict2[c]['consumption'])
    utc = (dict2[c]['interval_end'])
    date = utc[5:10]  # slicing from the elemnet in utc
    time = utc[11:16] # slicing from the elemnet in utc
    t = f"{date} {time}"
    print(t)
    time_period.append(t)
    c += 1

# I plot my data 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time_period, consumption, linewidth=3)
# set chart titkle and axis title
ax.set_title("Octopus Energy Usage", fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel("KwH", fontsize = 14)
ax.set_xlabel("Date/Time", fontsize = 14)
plt.show()
```

Anyway the above code works fine but I end up with a chart that is basically unreadable (See x-axis in the graph below).

So my question is: Is there a way to tell the api to only send a whole or half days data (rather than hourly data) or is there a way I can sum the data that I get back from the API and use the chart to show the summed data. As an FYI the data teh API sends back is like the following.
Thanks

```
2021-02-18 23:00:00+00:00    0.102 
2021-02-18 22:30:00+00:00    0.118
2021-02-18 22:00:00+00:00    0.153
2021-02-18 21:30:00+00:00    0.133
2021-02-18 21:00:00+00:00    0.185
```

[image: example graph]